# Dependency injection in validator

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, jhipster

I can't inject entity repository in a custom validator.
I'm pretty new to java, spring and jHipster so i'm a bit lost in the answers in similar questions.

What I have :

an Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "building_floor",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name="buildingFloor",columnNames = {"building_id","name"}))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@BuildingFloorUnicityValidator
public class BuildingFloor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 32)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Building building;
    //...
```

a custom annotation :

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = BuildingFloorUnicityValidatorCheck.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface BuildingFloorUnicityValidator {

    String message() default "{builindg floor already exists}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String value() default "";
}
```

a validator :

```
public class BuildingFloorUnicityValidatorCheck implements ConstraintValidator<BuildingFloorUnicityValidator, BuildingFloor> {

    @Autowired
    private BuildingFloorRepository buildingFloorRepository;



    @Override
    public void initialize(BuildingFloorUnicityValidator constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(BuildingFloor value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        BuildingFloor existingBuilindg = buildingFloorRepository.findOneByBuildingAndName(value.getBuilding(),value.getName());

        return existingBuilindg == null;
    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/building-floors")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<BuildingFloorDTO> createBuildingFloor(@Valid @RequestBody BuildingFloorDTO buildingFloorDTO)
```

So when I launch tests the repository in the validator throws a NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at eu.***.master_data.validator.unicity.BuildingFloorUnicityValidatorCheck.isValid(BuildingFloorUnicityValidatorCheck.java:31)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` cannot be interpreted by Spring because `BuildingFloorUnicityValidatorCheck` is not a spring bean, you must annotate it with `@Service` or `@Component` or instantiate it from a `@Configuration` annotated class.

By the way, JHipster and Spring favour constructor injection over field injection (what you used). All services in JHipster use this way of doing, so you'll find many examples in your project.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work with `@Service` annotation it's still null in the `@Autowired` way and trigger error in the constructor way. `javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: class eu.***.master_data.validator.location.LocationBuildingIntegrityValidatorCheck.
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:42)...
`

Comment: It's not the same validator than in the original exemple but it's the same structure.